# Display a msg in Tkinter GUI when a function has completed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple `Tkinter` GUI with a button that runs a function to import a file from a local directory..

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x800")

def import_from_file():
    imported_file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [("All Files" , ".html")])
    html_string = open(imported_file_name, 'r')

import_button = tk.Button(root, text= "Import html from file", command = import_from_file)
import_button.place(x=10, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

My question is, what is the best way to display a message in the `Tkinter` GUI eg `"Finshed"` when that function has run, without closing the GUI?

If i use:

```
def import_from_file():
    imported_file_name = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [("All Files" , ".html")])
    html_string = open(imported_file_name, 'r')
    print('Finished')
```

This will only display `Finished` in the terminal when the `Tkinter GUI` is closed if it runs successfully.

Comment: Create a `Label` widget.

Comment: or use module [tkinter.messagebox](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.messagebox.html) to display popup dialog box with message.